# Is it possible to use SQL Server session state with a stateless web api application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We have a stateless web api application where we only use the token(obtained on login) as an identifier, which we decrypt, determine user and perform the action.

We now need to store a rather big object in session and it is a load balanced environment so SQL Server session state seems like a good fit.

Is it possible to use session in a stateless web api application?

Comment: Make sure to properly sign the tokens; there are various subtle crypto issues with such a scheme.

Comment: If you simply want to store some sort of large object that is always fetched by the session key then you may want to consider a clustered key value store instead. I'd recommend something like RIAK -- SQl server is pretty overkill for stuff like this -- if you don't want to run queries.

Comment: What I mean is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx but with "SQL Server Mode"

Comment: Yeah -- I got that but load balancing sql server is a bit of a nightmare -- you'll be tying your load balanced pool of web servers to 1 database server -- when you want to scale out you'll need to handle sql server replication etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a session in a stateless Web API then it would no longer be stateless.  So which do you want, stateless, or sessions?

Comment: I need to keep it stateless, but store a particular object at any time and be able to recover it quickly in an easy and efficient way. I know it sounds a bit confusing.

Comment: @xmorera Store the object, and assign it a URI, now it becomes resource state, instead of session state.  Magic!

Comment: Thanks @Darrel! Let me talk with the architect.